# Converting Dynamic disk to Basic disk

Tags: windows-8

[image]

I tried many utilities like partition magic etc  which ever I can google

I can't see any option to convert to basic.

Answer (score 1):

#### I can't see any option to convert to basic

You need to "Delete Volume" first.

---

#### Change a Dynamic Disk Back to a Basic Disk

> 1. Back up all volumes on the disk you want to convert from dynamic to basic.
> 2. In "Disk Management", right-click each volume on the dynamic disk you want to convert to a basic disk, and then click "Delete
>      Volume" for each volume on the disk.
> 3. When all volumes on the disk have been deleted, right-click the disk, and then click "Convert to Basic Disk."

Source [Change a Dynamic Disk Back to a Basic Disk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238.aspx)